# SqliteCaseReader' object has no attribute 'system_options' in openAeroStruct

Tags: python, openmdao

I'm using OpenAeroStruct from mdolab to simulate Aerodynamic Optimization. I used the example described here: https://mdolab-openaerostruct.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/aero_walkthrough.html. The optmization works fine, but when I try to run: plot_wing aero_analysis_test.db, I got the error: SqliteCaseReader' object has no attribute 'system_options'. Someone knows how can I fix it?

I checked that openmdao is updated and installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue has been posted to the OpenAeroStruct repo that explains the problem:
https://github.com/mdolab/OpenAeroStruct/issues/407

The workaround is to install `openmdao<3.26.0` until OpenAeroStruct has been updated.